# How do I add space between elements in list comprehension? Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a matrix with this:

```
table = [list('*'*4) for i in range(4)]
```

how do I add empty spaces between every element ('*')?

Comment: It is not clear what you want.

Comment: maybe `zzz = ' '.join(table)` ?